# How to select a row from dynamic table on mouseclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spry

How can get a row's value on mouse click or `checking the checkbox preferably` from the below given html table?

Here is the `js` for getting values for my table from a xml using spry

```
var ds1 = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("xml/data.xml", "rows/row"); 
var pv1 = new Spry.Data.PagedView( ds1 ,{ pageSize: 10 , forceFullPages:true, useZeroBasedIndexes:true});
var pvInfo = pv1.getPagingInfo();
```

Here is the `Div` with `spry` region containing the table that gets populated from `pv1` (see js part)

```
<div id="configDiv" name="config" style="width:100%;" spry:region="pv1">

    <div spry:state="loading">Loading - Please stand by...</div>
    <div spry:state="error">Oh crap, something went wrong!</div>

    <div spry:state="ready">

    <table id="tableDg" onclick="runEffect('Highlight', 'trEven', {duration: 1000, from: '#000000', to: '#805600', restoreColor: '#805600', toggle:true}, 'Flashes a color as the background of an HTML element.')"
    style="border:#2F5882 1px solid;width:100%;"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"> 

    <thead>
     <tr id="trHead" style="color :#FFFFFF;background-color: #8EA4BB"> 
         <th width="2%"><input id="chkbHead" type='checkbox' /></th>
         <th width="10%" align="center" spry:sort="name"><b>Name</b></th> 
         <th width="22%" align="center" spry:sort="email"><b>Email</b></th> 

     </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody spry:repeat="pv1">   
     <tr class="trOdd"   
     spry:if="({ds_RowNumber} % 2) != 0" onclick="ds1.setCurrentRow('{ds_RowID}');"
        style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #FFFFFF"> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbTest" class = "chkbCsm"></input></td>
         <td width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{name}</td> 
         <td width="22%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{email}</td> 

     </tr> 

     <tr class="trEven" name="trEven" id="trEven"
     spry:if="({ds_RowNumber} % 2) == 0" onclick="ds1.setCurrentRow('{ds_RowID}');"
        style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #EDF1F5;"> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chkbCsm"></input></td>
         <td id="tdname" width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{name}</td> 
         <td width="22%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{email}</td> 

     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table> 
     </div>
     </div>
```

I am trying the below code but still I am not getting the alert and hence none of the answers are also not working. I know the syntax n all are everything correct, but i am not able to figure out what is the problem here!

```
//inside $(document).ready(function()
$("#chkbHead").click(function() {
    alert("Hi");
});
```

My page has other tables too for aligning some contents. So when I use the below code it works perfectly on those tables except the one in the question. It might be the problem because there are only 2 `tr` in the table which gets populated by a spry dataset and hence not getting identified properly. May be, I am not sure, just trying to help improve my understanding

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    alert("by");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by value of a table row?  You can get the inner html of a table row like this:

```
var html = '';
$('tr').click(function() {
    html = $(this).html();
});
```

You can get attributes of the table row (e.g. it's Id) like so:

```
var id = '';
$('tr').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Alternatively you can get the value of nested elements such as a text input like so:

```
var text = '';
$('tr').click(function() {
    text = $(this).find('#myTextBox').val();
});
```

**EDIT**

This is how to change the checked attribute of a checkbox nested in a table row:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    // alternatively make it unchecked
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', '');
});
```

**EDIT**

As the table rows are being loaded dynamically - the $().click() event binding method will not work, because when you are calling it - the table rows do not exist, so the click event cannot be bound to them. Instead of using $().click use the jQuery live method:

```
$('tr').live('click', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

This binds the click event to all current table rows and all table rows that may be added in the future. [See the jQuery docs here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: By `value` I mean the element values of a particular row, such as `input type="checkbox" selected or unselected`, `name` and `email` of that particular row

Comment: I have shown you how to do that in the last code snippet - that is selecting the value of a text box nested in a table row - I will edit my answer to show how to check a checkbox this way

Comment: @dormisher: i tried your solution but nothing happened, it seems the answer is correct. Read my edited question please.

Comment: are the table rows being loaded dynamically, or are they loaded with the rest of the page content?

Comment: @dormisher: table rows are loaded dynamically

Comment: @dormisher: 1 more quick question, I want to `highlight` 1st row after I add a new row, so for that i wrote a js function which adding and just after addition i wrote `$("#tableDg tbody tr:first").live().css({
  "background-color": "red"
 });` to highlight, but its not getting affected

Comment: remove the .live() bit from what you just wrote and it will work - you will need to call that piece of code every time you want to highlight the first row

Comment: @dormisher: I removed the live() but not happening

Comment: ahh I see what it is - try this `$("#tableDg tbody tr:first").css("background-color", "red");` if that doesnt work, make sure it is actually being called by debugging, and change the reference to just 'tr' to see if it turns all table rows to red

Comment: @dormisher: Neither `tr` nor `#tableDg tbody tr:first` is showing any effect

Comment: @dormisher: but yes when i tried this `$('#tableDg tr').live('click', function() {
  text = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();
  }).css("background-color", "red");` it made all my rows red on click

Comment: well it should work - the problem must lie elswhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

The values of a Row you will get with:

```
$('#tableDg tbody tr').live( 'click', function (event) {
    $(this).find('td').each( function( index, item ) {
       if ( $(this).has(':checkbox') ) {
          alert( $(this).find(':checkbox').val() );
       } else {
          alert( $(this).text() );
       }
    };
});
```

Comment: @Daniel: Hi thanks for your reply, seems like it should work. But i tried a simple test (see my edited question) which is not working neither your solution.

Comment: where did you placed that code? place it after all HTML or within a `document.ready()`

Comment: @DanielB: I placed the code inside `$(document).ready(function()` function

Comment: Okay, the problem is that the data is applied dynamically so you have to use `live()`. Ive updated my post

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **Spry Observer**,
something like this:

```
function funcObserver(notificationState, notifier, data) {
    var rgn = Spry.Data.getRegion('configDiv');
    st = rgn.getState();
    if (notificationState == "onPostUpdate" && st == 'ready') {
        // HERE YOU CAN USE YOUR JQUERY CODE
        $('#tableDg tbody tr').click(function() {
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
            // alternatively make it unchecked
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', '');
        });
    }
}
Spry.Data.Region.addObserver("configDiv", funcObserver);
```